# ordering in boxplot according to an object

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot, seaborn

I would like to have some grouped boxplot in a pandas df.

var2 is an object, and I would like to display the boxplot in alphabetical order according to var2 order

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("whitegrid")   
ax = sns.boxplot(x="var1", y="var2",order=???, data=df)
```

without putting manually: order=["a","b","c","d","e"]

Answer (score 3):

Not 100% sure what needs to be sorted, but essentially you need to use unique():

```
order = sorted(df.var1.unique())
ax = sns.boxplot(x="var1", y="var2", order=order, data=df)
```