# Keep weekdays ordered on pandas boxplot using seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a simple dataset with days on it:

```
dt, value, coltype
2017-01-01, 10, A 
2017-01-02, 11, B
2017-01-03, 30, A
2017-01-04, 90, C
2017-01-05, 9,  A
2017-01-06, 13, E
2017-01-07, 12, C
2017-01-08, 10, B
```

and I want to create a simple boxplot based on weekdays:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = read_csv('mycsv.txt')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.dt)
sns.boxplot(x=df.index.weekday_name, y=value)
```

and what I get is a boxplot but with the week days not ordered:
[image: boxplot]

Is there a way do it directly on the boxplot function, without creating another column?

Comment: It seems like it is ordered (started from Sunday), are you looking to have it starting on Monday?

Comment: That's actually... lucky. I created the data randomly as an example. The real example has the dt legend with the wrong order. It doesn't actually sort on the real example.

Comment: Sort your dataframe by index then plot like you are doing here.

Comment: The dataframe is already sorted by index.

Comment: @Ivan Does your real data set have missing dates? It seems like if all you dates exists and they are sorted, the plot is correct, but as long as you have one missing date (for example, missing 2017-01-03), then the order breaks.

Comment: Is there anything unclear in the boxplot documentation about the `order` argument? Also see [this quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38143927/ordering-in-boxplot-according-to-an-object).

Comment: I missed the `order` argument and the poster below kindly showed an example, although I have to provide the order by myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `order` parameter:

```
order = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
sns.boxplot(x=df.index.weekday_name, y=df.value, order=order)
```

If your dates are complete and contains data for every weekday, you will get something like:

[image]

If say you don't have data for one of the weekday and still call the same code, you get something like:

[image]

which is totally fine (at least for me), and you can also clearly see that there's no data for Tuesday, which tells you more about your data as well.